# Material-ui Table sorting not working reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Good Day! Currently using Material-ui table, and I'm having an issue on sorting. I followed what's on the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) but sorting is not working on my side.

Here's my code:

```
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableFooter from '@material-ui/core/TableFooter'
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import TableSortLabel from '@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel';

function descendingComparator(a,b, orderBy) {
  console.log('a',a)
  console.log('b',b)
  console.log('orderBy',orderBy)
  if(b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]){
    console.log('-1')
    return -1;
  }
  if(b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]){
    console.log('1')
    return 1;
  }
  console.log('0')
  return 0;
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy){
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a,b) => descendingComparator(a,b, orderBy)
    : (a,b) => -descendingComparator(a,b, orderBy)
}

const sortedRowInformation = (rowArray, comparator) => {
  const stabilizedRowArray = rowArray.map((el, index) => [el, index])
  stabilizedRowArray.sort((a,b) =>{
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0])
    if(order !==0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
})
return stabilizedRowArray.map((el) => el[0])
}

function Test(){
  const [dummyDatas, setdummyDatas] = useState([])
  const getInformation= async () => {
    await axios.get('/API')
        .then(response => {
            setdummyDatas(response.dummyDatas)
        })
  }
}

useEffect(()=>{
  getInformation()
})

const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5)
const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(0)
const [order, setOrder] = useState()
const [orderBy, setorderBy] = useState()
const [orderDirection, setorderDirection] = useState("asc")
const [valueToOrderBy, setvalueToOrderBy] = useState("details")

return(
 <div>
   <TableContainer component={Paper}>
     <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="information table">
       <TableHead>
         <TableRow>
           <TableCell align = "left" key = "details">
             <TableSortLabel
                active={valueToOrderBy === "details"}
                direction={valueToOrderBy === "details" ? orderDirection: 'asc'}
                onClick={createSortHandle("details")}
             >
                Details
             </TableSortLabel>
           </TableCell>
           <TableCell align = "left" key = "status">
             <TableSortLabel
               active={valueToOrderBy === "status"}
               direction={valueToOrderBy === "status" ? orderDirection: 'asc'}
               onClick={createSortHandle("status")}
             >
               Status
             </TableSortLabel>
           </TableCell>
           <TableCell align = "left" key = "system">
             <TableSortLabel
               active={valueToOrderBy === "system"}
               direction={valueToOrderBy === "system" ? orderDirection: 'asc'}
               onClick={createSortHandle("system")}
             >
               System
             </TableSortLabel>
           </TableCell>
         </TableRow>
       </TableHead>
       <TableBody>
         {
           sortedRowInformation(dummyDatas, getComparator(orderDirection, valueToOrderBy))
           .map((row, index1) => (
                        <TableRow key={index1}>
                            <TableCell>
                                        {row.ADVISORYTITLE}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                        {row.STATUS}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                        {row.SYSTEMID}
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
       </TableBody>
     </Table>
   </TableContainer>
 </div>
)
```

Upon clicking the sorting arrow on status column nothing happens. This is my `console.log` looks like.
[image]

Hoping that you could help me with this. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What changes did you made? I face the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make you valueToOrderBy same as your data columns. (Eg. ADVISORYTITLE)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Bumped on this after days of struggling. It was weird that one of my columns was not sorting properly while other similar columns were sorting properly. As pointed here - the "valueToOrderBy" (in TableSortLabel components) should match the corresponding attribute name or data column (Eg. ADVISORYTITLE here) in the list of data items (Eg. dummyDatas here or whatever list is coming from your API). 

Although I don't understand why its required that way. Would appreciate if someone could throw light on that too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you are using the same values for your column name and valueToOrderBy otherwise it will not be able to do the comparison.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).